# How can I write an input selector for the states API?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the `#states` API but my input selector isn't being picked up.  This is the code I've added to `hook_form_alter()` in a custom module:

```
  case 'my_form':
    $form['revision_information']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['field_guide_link_hosting']['#states'] = array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_guide_types[und]"]' => array('value' => 's'),
      ),
      'required' => array(
        ':input[name="field_guide_types[und]"]' => array('value' => 's'),
      ),
    );
```

And here's the rendered form for `field_guide_types`:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-checkboxes form-item-field-guide-types-und">
  <label for="edit-field-guide-types-und">How can you help tourists? <span class="form-required" title="This field cannot be left blank.">必須</span></label>
 <div id="edit-field-guide-types-und" class="form-checkboxes"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-guide-types-und-o">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-guide-types-und-o" name="field_guide_types[und][o]" value="o" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-guide-types-und-o">Answer questions and offer information online </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-guide-types-und-m">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-guide-types-und-m" name="field_guide_types[und][m]" value="m" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-guide-types-und-m">Meet in person </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-guide-types-und-s">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-guide-types-und-s" name="field_guide_types[und][s]" value="s" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-guide-types-und-s">Provide a place to stay (like through AirBNB, CouchSurfing, etc.) </label>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`drupal_process_states()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7) has a great set of information on handling inputs for different types of input elements.

You have checkboxes, so you have to use `checked` assertion.

```
case 'my_form':
    $form['revision_information']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['field_guide_link_hosting']['#states'] = array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_guide_types[und][s]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
      ),
      'required' => array(
        ':input[name="field_guide_types[und][s]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE
      ),
    );
```

Notice I replaced the `value` assertion with a checked, and also changed the jQuery selector to use the full `name` attribute of the checkbox.